# Function of a specific phrase in a sentence

Tags: modifiers

In the following sentence, what is the function of "not, as one might assume, in English"? For example, is it some type of clause that modifies "wrote"?

The Irish author Samuel Beckett originally wrote his most famous play, *Waiting for Godot*, in French, not, as one might assume, in English.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "as one might assume" is a [non-essential phrase](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/607/05/).

If you remove it from the sentence, it will make it easier to comprehend:

> The Irish author Samuel Beckett originally wrote his most famous play, *Waiting for Godot*, in French, not in English.

Here you can see that the sentence simply says that the play was written in French, not English.

What the non-essential phrase is doing is emphasizing the fact that the Beckett wrote the play in a language other than his native English.

Comment: +1. The non-essential phrase could have been tacked onto the end:  *... in French, not in English as one might assume.*